# File transformation, is it possible to add autoincrement to a setting

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, build-automation, teamcity, transformation

In our automatic build we use `MSBuild` in combination with web.config [transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) to create an acceptance config and a production config.

We have added attributes to change config settings

for example to change the cdn url's.

```
<add key="cdn1url" value="http://cdn.acceptance.oursite.com/"
                   xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" 
                   xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
```

Does anybody know if it is possible to add an autoincrement attribute? We want to add `+1` to the version attribute (for `css/img/js` caching) on every production build.

An other option could be the `Teamcity` build number, but I am not sure if that is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You already have the Current or even Next Version number as msbuild property value - see `3`
2. You do not have it -> see `PS` at the bottom and then back to `3`
3. You can do it using [FileUpdate](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) task by providing a regexp and replacement text with a new version number:

---

```
 <FileUpdate
      Files="@(FilesToUpdate)"
      Regex="regex here"
      ReplacementText="$(NextVersionNumber)" />
```

---

PS: By using `RegexMatch` task you can extract current version and then by incrementing it you'll get a value for the `$(NextVersionNumber)` proeprty.